# Google Maps API Ver2 retired?

Tags: google-maps-api-2

I read something recently that google maps api ver 2 will be retired.  I know that it is already deprecated.

Is any one aware if this is true?  Basically is there a point and time when Ver2 will stop working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Google, [The V2 API will continue to work until May 19, 2013](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference). So yes, it will be retired and no longer functional at that point. However, you can develop using the [Google AJAX API loader](https://developers.google.com/loader/), as the [Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/) has been integrated into it. It also continues to rely on Javascript for scripting and development. Google recommends that developers move to [version 3 of the API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/).

So yes, Google is definitely retiring version 2. They have deprecated version 2, they have recommended moving to version 3, and they look to be [actively promoting development](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/) using Google Maps on the version 3 platform.

Comment: Thanks for your answer found this right as you guys were posting.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case anyone reads this, the retirement has been extended to November 19th 2013.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference

Answer (score 2):

May 19, 2013, it seems...
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference

Comment: Thanks for your answer found this right as you guys were posting.