# How to migrate code from Google Maps API V2 to V3?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

As the Google Maps JavaScript API Version 2 has been officially deprecated as of May 19, 2010. The V2 API will stop to work after May 19, 2013.

Does all the applications which we have develop using V2 going to stop after May19, 2013 and we have to migrate these to V3 before this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API Ver2 retired?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180774/google-maps-api-ver2-retired)

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if google has expressly said that they will remove the API and assets from being able to be used, but I do know that after May 19, all bets are off, they are free to take down the API and any/all assets that are required to support v2 at any time without notice, so it's kind of an "at own risk" deal.

It's time for you to migrate over....v2 has been deprecated for years and v3 is very well supported.

It's not ridiculously hard to migrate over, you can probably keep the majority of your existing codebase and just call a few different functions.

For instance, all of the original functions that you used to call like this:

```
new GMap2()...
new GMarker()...
new GLatLng()...
```

Have all been namespaced, so their equivalents in v3 would be:

```
new google.maps.Map()...
new google.maps.Marker()...
new google.maps.LatLng()...
```

Any time you'd be using services, however, like StreetView or DirectionsRenderer, you'd need to check the docs on that because those have changed slightly.

You'll have to chase some bugs down as you go through, but the docs are very very well organized and you shouldn't have that much trouble.

Best of luck!

Comment: Also, please note, an API key is not needed to use v3... so even easier.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an easy guide on how to do the upgrade: http://gabrielduque.wordpress.com/2011/01/13/upgrading-from-google-maps-api-v2-to-v3/

Comment: Answers that are mostly links are discouraged, can you summerize for the answer?

Comment: That link is going to get destroyed today since they killed the v2 api last night. Also, following those steps didn't work for me, but our use of the API is ridiculously over complicated.