# What is the impact of deprecated Google Maps JavaScript API V2?

Tags: google-maps-api-2

I have a client that has Google Maps using JavaScript API v2 on their websites, which will eventually be deprecated (discontinued/not supported) until May 19, 2013 according to
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/introduction

**I just like to know what are the *impacts* on the website if I do not yet upgrade my code to JavaScript API v3** by May 19? e.g. Will my Google Map API v2 stop working (because Google has taken v2 API offline)

I ask this question because I have 6 websites that needs to be upgraded to API v3 and may not meet the deadline by May 19.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API Ver2 retired?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180774/google-maps-api-ver2-retired)

Answer (score 0):

One possible implication is Google Web Toolkit, which is not (and will not) be supported in Google Maps v3.  If you have a complex, large site built with GWT, using v2 and you haven't already rewritten your site.. you may be [up the creek](http://www.advrider.com/forums/showpost.php?p=20945810&postcount=1572).